# Создать локальный принтер с запись в файл

Tags: windows, print

Пытаюсь из командной строки создать принтер (Windows10)

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "MyTestPrinter" /r "nul:" /m "Generic / Text Only"
```

Принтер создался и появился в списке, но еще необходимо, что бы он "печатал" в тестовый файл.
Если делать как описано [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/printing/print-to-file-without-user-intervention?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-Ujknvu1auHszDgGOjOo.2w&epi=a1LgFw09t88-Ujknvu1auHszDgGOjOo.2w&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=%28ir__toy6dpxvi0kf6xkogy0hdlxbqu2xrapqbefnf3jj00%29%287806%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-Ujknvu1auHszDgGOjOo.2w%29%28%29&irclickid=_toy6dpxvi0kf6xkogy0hdlxbqu2xrapqbefnf3jj00) то все создается нормально, если же пытаюсь в название порта прописать текстовый файл:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "MyTestPrinter" /r "D:\Printresults.txt" /m "Generic / Text Only"
```

получаю ошибку: **Указанный порт не существует**

Подскажите, как правильно задать параметры локального порта? Спасибо!

Comment: Зачем Вы в название порта хотите записать "текстовый файл"?

Comment: что бы потом «печатать» в этот тестовый файл, в графическом интерфейсе так работает

Comment: Тогда что в Вашем представлении делает в системе "Название порта". Почему именно в него нужно печатать Ваш файл?

Comment: А почему Вы не указываете порт: `файл` - `file:` ? то есть при создании принтера нужно задать параметр: `/r "file:"`

Comment: так тоже не пропускает - Указанный порт не существует

Comment: кажется я понял в чём Ваша проблема. Вы создаете принтер и указываете порт. Но такой порт **не существует**. Вначале создайте такой локальный порт `D:\Printresults.txt`. Как это сделать не вручную, а средствами автоматизации: это совсем другой вопрос, отличный от того, что задали Вы.

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось чуть-чуть хитрее, нужно ранее создать порт командой **Add-PrinterPort**

```
Add-PrinterPort -Name "D:\MyTestPrinter.txt"
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "MyTestPrinter" /r "D:\MyTestPrinter.txt" /m "Generic / Text Only"
```

Comment: А давайте Вы уточните ответ: распишете целиком успешно выполненные команды. Это принесет пользу.

Comment: Я полагаю, Вам следует уточнить, что команды вызывались с приложения `Windows Powershell ISE`